# BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics for exotic unicode glyphs

Tags: regions, conversion, fonts, discretization, unicode

This code works

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text@"\[WolframLanguageLogoCircle]\[WolframLanguageLogo]", _Text]
```

[image: wolfs]

But for more exotic characters, it produces the null rectangle in whatever font is internally used

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text@"व", _Text]
```

[image]

I've tried

```
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Style[Text@"व", FontFamily -> "Times"], _Text]
```

but the function seems to ignore the Style wrapper.  It's a kernel function, so I don't know how to probe it.

I'm aware of other methods to get the outline (Export Import tricks), but BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics would be more convenient.

Comment: Work on Win 11, mma 13.1 version. `t = Text[Style["व", FontFamily -> "Times", 15]];
BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[t, _Text, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]`

Comment: Currently on a Mac with 12.1, would be curious if this is a version issue or an OS/font issue.

Comment: Works with v12.2 through 13.1

Comment: On v12.2.0 Win7-x64 it draws a rectangle without the cross inside it.

Comment: It is interesting that `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text@"\[WolframLanguageLogoCircle]\[WolframLanguageLogo]", _Text]` doesn't work properly with *Mathematica* 13.1.0 and 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64, while `BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Text@"व", _Text]` works as expected: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJmpE.png) (the eye of the wolf is missing for `\[WolframLanguageLogoCircle]`).